# How can I make UML component diagram of Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, components

I have to make UML component diagram of Hadoop MapReduce.

Please advice on some resources available or approach how to go about it.
I have already checked apache hadoop wiki etc. and have the basic picture. I need to make a detailed component diagram with all the components involved to make MapReduce .

I am only concerned with MapReduce. I have tried reading the source code but I am not able to understand from where to start. How to get hold of the control flow of the execution through the source code of MapReduce.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good basic knowledge about different component involved in the MapReduce application can be derived from the courses available on [official big data university website](http://bigdatauniversity.com), such as "Introduction to MapReduce Programming", and then try to derive the component diagram, basically you need to elaborate the MapReduce execution engine.

Check this pdf for one such indicative diagram (figure 5): [link to pdf](http://grid.deis.unical.it/papers/pdf/PDP2011.pdf).